# How should I post literate code?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Suppose I have a project that is written in a literate format (e.g., emacs org-mode), and I would like to have that code reviewed.  What is the preferred way to post the code?

Some options that come immediately to mind are:

- Preserve the literate form of the program.  It depends on the project, but there's likely to be quite a bit of prose surrounding the actual code.  Even [very small libraries](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.thread-local/blob/cd1c8facbcf30f151cbd35a920e1e1cf63f43cad/Readme.org) may be relatively long when expressed in literate form.  This makes the code clear, but is not necessarily concise.
- Post the extracted code.  This keeps the post short, but is not necessarily clear.
- Post the extracted code, possibly including select portions of the prose, and link to the full literate version -- preferably a specific version under revision control.

However, I'm sure there are other options that are worth considering as well.

Also, it could very well be the case that there is no single approach that fits in all situations.  If that's the case, what are some heuristics for choosing the right approach?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Code Review wants to see your code in context.  In general, you should post the "real" code in the state that you normally work with.  If it's literate code, then post it as literate code.  To get the best value out of Code Review, avoid sanitizing your code just for the sake of posting a question.

Comment: We're not worried about "post-processing" on your code, only about what *you are directly dealing with*.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you mean I should post the raw *markup* or a *rendered* form of the document?

Comment: I think that @Quuxplusone has the right idea. Whatever format you normally use to work with the code is the most important. I assume that that would be the raw markup. The rendered form could be helpful as well, but would be of secondary importance.

Answer (score 6):

If I were going to post some WEB or CWEB code for review, I would definitely post the raw *source* code, but I would also provide [a link to download the "woven" (PDF) version](http://www.literateprogramming.com/krcwsamp.pdf), because that's the "presentation" format — it's not the code, but it *is* the code's output/behavior, which is fair game for reviewers to comment on, if it's suboptimal in some way. Compare what the best answers on TeX SE do: [post the code, but also post the output.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343151/start-algorithm-step-numbering-not-at-1)

I would *not* post, nor link to, the "tangled" (compiled) code, any more than I'd post the assembly output of a C++ program I wanted reviewed.

The [very small library](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.thread-local/blob/cd1c8facbcf30f151cbd35a920e1e1cf63f43cad/Readme.org) you linked to is a bit of a special case, I would hope, in that it's not really "literate code" so much as "plain old code, but archived in a special non-compressed format where each file must be preceded by a header describing (in English) how trivial this particular next file is." :)  Still, if you're posting it on CodeReview, I think [the raw source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.thread-local/cd1c8facbcf30f151cbd35a920e1e1cf63f43cad/Readme.org) is the most relevant format, because that's the format that's going to be edited, grepped, and generally software-engineered.

In general, I suspect literate code doesn't make for good CodeReview questions, just because of how big and tangly literate programs ironically tend to be. Maybe this is because I've only ever seen Knuth do it, but I've never seen a program where I felt like could pluck a page out of the middle of the program and understand or "code-review" it in isolation, any more than you could "book-review" a page out of the middle of somebody's novel. But — I'm looking forward to being proved wrong!

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply.  If I understand correctly, you advocate posting the raw markup, as opposed to presenting the document in a rendered form.  Isn't that akin to including raw documentation files in your post?

Comment: Yep. CodeReview is for the review of *code*, that is, text written by engineers and readable by both computers and other engineers. If you hide the code you've actually written, and instead post only the rendered *output* of the compiler... well... that's not very useful in this context.

Comment: Well, the tangled code should certainly be readable by engineers.  I understand your point about it not technically being the code in the way it's originally expressed.  But your analogy with object code just doesn't ring true to me.  A literate program is simply a document that just happens to have some code embedded in it.  Isn't it the *code* that is the center of the review, rather than the *markup* that used to express it?

Comment: @NathanDavis: "the tangled code should certainly be readable by engineers" — Well, I'd say that machine code should also be readable by certain types of engineers, at least with some pain. But that's not what we mean when we say "is this code readable". Here's an example of [a tangled CWEB program](http://www.club.cc.cmu.edu/~ajo/disseminate/tangled-advent.c) — it's kind of like trying to read the output of `gcc -E`. I stand by my answer: engineers write (and review) *source code*, not *compiled output*.

Comment: All I can say is that with the literate programs I have written, the tangled code is formatted in pretty much *exactly* the same as if I'd written the code by hand.  But that's not really my main point (tangled vs. untangled).  To me, the more pertinent question is:  rendered document or raw markup.  If I'm not mistaken, you advocate posting the raw markup.  But like I said before -- it's the *code* that's centric, not the raw *markup*.  Any thoughts / counter-points in that regard?

Comment: @NathanDavis: I think we're talking past each other. I'll try one more time, but I believe I'm just repeating myself. "If you ask me to review your CUDA code, I'll want to see the *code*, not the rendered output. If you ask me to review your HTML code, I'll want to see the *code*, not the rendered output. If you ask me to review your TeX code, I'll want to see the *code*, not the rendered output. If you ask me to review your CWEB code, I'll want to see the *code*, not the rendered output." If you never review their source code, then how will the questioner ever learn to write good source code?